# A função set do estado do react não está realmente recebendo e repassando os valores

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, promises, react-hooks

Eu não sei pq, mas quando eu tento fazer uma requisição pro meu backend, o estado de "posts" não recebe o valor de response.data. Ou seja os dois "console.log" possuem valores diferentes, enquanto o response.data está correto o segundo retorna um array vazio. O que pode ser?

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function postLoader() {
        const response = await api.get('/posts');
        setPosts(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(posts);
    }

    postLoader();
}, []);
```

---

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5"
  }
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
```

---

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333',
});

export default api;
```

Comment: Qual é o problema exatamente? Imagino que seu problema não esteja no código mostrado. O valor de um estado só é atualizado após re-renderizar o componente, ele não vai mudar dentro do `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

`setPosts(response.data);` é um método assíncrono, isso significa que o novo estado não é setado instantaneamente. Quando o método `console.log(posts)` é chamado, o valor do seu estado ainda não foi alterado, dando a impressão de que não está sendo setado o novo valor.

Para printar o novo valor, use o hook `useEffect` e passando no array de dependências a sua variável **posts**. Dessa forma, assim que o estado for alterado, ela terá o novo valor printado:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(posts)
}, [posts]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Retire a função `postLoader()` de dentro do `useEffect(()=>{},[])`, por questão de legibilidade;

**2.** O método  setPosts e qualquer um que venha do useState(), não atualiza imediatamente, ou seja isso faz com que mesmo que você faça `setPosts(response.data);` e em seguida o `console.log(posts)` a variavel `posts` ainda não estará atualizada, pois isso demora um **pouquinho** mais.

**3.** Recomendo que faça assim:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(posts)
},[posts]) //passar a variavel 'posts' aqui fará com que este useEffect execute somente quando 'posts'  trocar de valor, ou seja um 'console.log()' aqui sempre exibirá correto.

useEffect(() => {    
    await postLoader();
}, []);`

async function postLoader() {
    const response = await api.get('/posts');
    setPosts(response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
}
```